# Objects are not valid as a React child error in Datatable

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, datatable

OK, so Im getting this error when trying to return some data from my web api.  Ive tried all as suggested on other similar posts but cant get this working. Any help appreciated.

*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {addressType, address1, address2, city, county, postCode, country, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

data...

```
"rows": [
        {
            "company": null,
            "controlPanel": null,
            "name": "Basement",
            "cloudAccessEnabled": true,
            "notes": "quad volcans quad quo si imaginator volcans brevens, nomen gravum Multum plorum brevens, in e quo quad",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressType": "HeadOffice, Marketing",
                    "address1": "729 Rocky First Blvd.",
                    "address2": "APT 22",
                    "city": "Haverhill",
                    "county": "Dunbartonshire",
                    "postCode": "SL1 9GH",
                    "country": null,
                    "id": "62a494ee-37cf-3021-5a29-00b54adc9255"
                }
            ],
            "installers": null,
            "lastMaintenance": "2016-06-30T00:00:00",
            "nextMaintenance": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "latestResult": "None Yet",
            "id": "c0d44330-8369-0e78-f45b-000142b59fa8"
        },
```

how I am trying to display in datatable...
https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component

```
//this works
//cell: row => <div>{row.notes}</div>,

//doesnt work-Objects are not valid as a React child error
    cell: row => (
        <div>
          {row.addresses.map((addressType, id) => (
            <div key={id}>{addressType}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ),
```

Comment: the `adressType` you are passing in your map function is not what you think you are passing, that adressType is actually your `addresses[i]` for that iteration so what you should do is: `<div key={adressType.id}>{adressType.adressType}</div>`. Change the `adressType` in map function to a better name like `address` then do `address.id` and `adress.adressType` and remove the `id` from your map function.

Comment: Or you could do what @JojoTutor said below and deconstruct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
cell: row => (
        <div>
          {row.addresses.map(({ addressType, id }) => (
            <div key={id}>{addressType}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks thats fixed the Objects are not valid as a React child error, but now im getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: That case maybe some "row" does not have "addresses" property,  try this: {row.addresses && row.addresses.map(({ addressType, id }) => (
            <div key={id}>{addressType}</div>
          ))}

Comment: Glad to help ...!